# why doesn't the function run within this timer?

Tags: c#

Why wouldn't the `Vote();` function run wihtin this timer?

The message box one works but vote one doesn't

```
public void Timer()
{
        var timespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(timespan.TotalMilliseconds);
        timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Worked");
            Vote();
        };
        timer.Start();
}
```

Vote is above this function within this code, Thanks, Oliver.

Comment: Provide the code for `Vote()` function.

Comment: Does it run when you click `Ok` for the `MessageBox` ?

Comment: Yes V4 and sai : http://pastebin.com/f1yKBCAH

Comment: How do you know the Vote function doesn't run. If the MessageBox shows then the Vote function must also have run!

Comment: It should write something into the rich text box. but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Timer.Elapsed` event suppresses all exceptions, causing you to not see any errors.  Add your own error handling in the `Elapsed` event to see what's failing.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx):

> The Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Uhm, no. Using a slash as a path delimiter in Windows is perfectly OK.

Comment: @Christian.K, I never knew that.  Thanks!  Any idea when that was introduced?  Edited my answer to keep the facts straight.

Comment: I don't have any reference, but I knew about it since "Windows NT", I guess. Anyway, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7314606/21567) has more information about directory separators on Windows (hint: Korean version, etc. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The elapsed timer code can run on a separate thread. If it does you could have a cross threaded violation. Can't know for sure without seeing the code for Vote. If you want to make sure the lambda is running writing a message out the console would be less disruptive than using a winform dialog box.