# Which is the correct way to define the output path in a C# project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, configuration-files

Recently i had to change my csproj files for some C# projects. I noticed that in same the output path for debug or release was set something like:

```
<OutputPath>Bin/Release</OutputPath>
<OutputPath>Bin/Degug</OutputPath>
```

Usually i set these paths (how i also noticed that the Visual Studio is adding by default this paths) using the \ like below:

```
<OutputPath>Bin\Release</OutputPath>
<OutputPath>Bin\Debug</OutputPath>
```

Interesting fact is that it seems that both ways are working as expected since after runing a build both cases are giving the same output build results in file explorer.

So, is there a difference between these two definitios ? Can both of them be used, or is there a recommended one ?

I would go for the \ definition since this one seems to be also the default one given by Visual Studio, but still i think that having some other opinions about this is welcomed.

Comment: I guess either is fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314606/get-directory-separator-char-on-windows-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way is fine as both Windows and Visual Studio treat `/` and `\` the same